# NSDictionary inside NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to put different instances of 1 dictionary into an array. Shared the expected and current output. Please suggest something
Thanks in advance

**Program.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray* array;
```

**Program.m**

```
-- (void)StartFuntion
 {
_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary* dicOne = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dicOne setObject:@"A" forKey:@"1"];        //Adding new
[dicOne setObject:@"B" forKey:@"2"];
[dicOne setObject:@"C" forKey:@"3"];
[dicOne setObject:@"D" forKey:@"4"];
[self addob:dicOne];                       //sending dicOne to funtion 

[dicOne removeAllObjects];              //Remove objects

[dicOne setObject:@"X" forKey:@"100"];      //Again Adding new objects
[dicOne setObject:@"Y" forKey:@"200"];
[dicOne setObject:@"Z" forKey:@"300"];
[dicOne setObject:@"W" forKey:@"400"];
[self addob:dicOne];
}


-- (void) addob:(NSMutableDictionary*)dic{

[_array addObject:dic];
NSLog(@"_array = %@",_array);

}
```

**Current Output:**

```
  _array = (
         {
    100 = X;
    200 = Y;
    300 = Z;
    400 = W;
},
    {
    100 = X;
    200 = Y;
    300 = Z;
    400 = W;
}
    )
```

**Expected output:**

```
  _array = (
     {
    1 = A;
    2 = B;
    3 = C;
    4 = D;
},
    {
    100 = X;
    200 = Y;
    300 = Z;
    400 = W;
  }
      )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reuse `dicOne`. Instead of removing its objects, create a new instance.

```
_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary* dicOne = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dicOne setObject:@"A" forKey:@"1"];        //Adding new
[dicOne setObject:@"B" forKey:@"2"];
[dicOne setObject:@"C" forKey:@"3"];
[dicOne setObject:@"D" forKey:@"4"];
[self addob:dicOne];                       //sending dicOne to funtion 

dicOne = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dicOne setObject:@"X" forKey:@"100"];      //Again Adding new objects
[dicOne setObject:@"Y" forKey:@"200"];
[dicOne setObject:@"Z" forKey:@"300"];
[dicOne setObject:@"W" forKey:@"400"];
[self addob:dicOne];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing an `NSMutableDictionary` instead of creating a new instance.  Do something like this instead...

```
[_array addObject:@{
                    @"1" : @"A",
                    @"2" : @"B",
                    @"3" : @"C",
                    @"4" : @"D",
                   }];

[_array addObject:@{
                    @"100" : @"X",
                    @"200" : @"Y",
                    @"300" : @"Z",
                    @"400" : @"W",
                   }];
```

Comment: FYI - you have the keys and values backward compared to the OP's code.

Comment: Just realized that.  There's a reason no one ever liked `[setValue:forKey:]`

Comment: Yeah because `[setObject:forKey:]` was better.

Comment: Yeah, yeah.  Whatever.  :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:dict1];
[array addObject:dict2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, but you have to make a copy of dic before inserting it in _array.

```
-- (void) addob:(NSMutableDictionary*)dic{
[_array addObject:[dic copy]];
NSLog(@"_array = %@",_array);
}
```

or use [dic mutableCopy] if you want mutable dict in your array.
You can also make the copy when you call addob: and not in the method.